# Sending and recieving int over network python

Tags: python

I am having a problem sending and receiving data.  This will be a number guessing game eventually but at the moment I am having difficulty sending the integer from client side and storing it to a variable on the server side.

I get the error message "TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface".  I am unsure what this means or how to fix it.

Thank you

```
#Server

import socket
import math
import re
import random

goal = random.randrange(1,11)

def within(guess,goal,n):
    absValue = abs(guess - goal)
    if absValue <= n:
        return True
    else:
        return False

scoreCount = 0
guess = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1",9000))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    (c,a) = s.accept()
    print ("Received connection from", a)

    while guess!= goal:
        c.sendall('What is your guess?'.encode())
        guess =(c.recv(4096))
        print(guess)

c.close()



#Client

import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1',9000))

data = s.recv(10000).decode()
print (data)


while True:

    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    print(guess)
    s.sendall(guess)
    s.close()
```

Comment: Try turning it into a bytearray `guess = bytes(int(input("Guess: ")))` (Python 3), or convert it to a string and back.

Comment: It didn't work I'm afraid

Comment: According to the docs, s.sendall() takes a byte array as an input. What error did you get when you sent the byte array?